# having external files in an electron application

Tags: electron

I have an electron app, and when I make it, it packages and compiles everything.

Sounds like it works perfectly right?

Well, problem is I want one of the folders to *not* be compiled, but still be accessible by my static files, so the users can add or remove content from the folders.

I've tried making it in a seperate folder, but then it can't find the files even when it's placed in the correct relative path.

Overall, I want my app to exist next to a folder and my `<script src="./folder/script.js"></script>` to actually be able to access it.

I'm new to basically anything node or electron so i'm probably making some dumb mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am new to electron too, and I followed their github quick start here : https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start

Answer (score 0):

Having your user touching files close to your Electron application may be fraught with danger. If they accidently overwrite an important file or accidently delete an important file then your application may stop working and require the user to perform a re-install.

Instead, have any default files the user may need to "touch" packaged up with your application and then upon your applications first run, copy these files (and any necessary folder structure) over to the users home, desktop, documents, downloads or even userData directory.

That way, your application will always know where to find them and the directory is a directory your user will already be comfortable adding files to and removing files from.

You can always let the use choose where these files are stored as a settings option which persists in an application setting file, using something similar to `path.join(app.getPath('userData'), 'settings.json');`

See Electron's [`app.getPath(name)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appgetpathname) for more information.